# How To Create Random Data For Primitive Types

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am looking to create some helper extensions to randomly populate a new object with properties for automated testing purposes, specifically I want to check that objects can be serialized and deserialized to json without any loss of data (from public properties).  The test I have written so far is:

```
public void MyTest()
{
    var sut = new MyClass().Populate();
    var sut2 = new MyClass().Populate();
    Assert.AreNotEqual(sut, sut2);  //ensure the Equals method distinguishes
    var serialised = JSonConvert.SerializeObject(sut);
    var result = JSonConvert.DeserializeObjct<MyClass>(serialised);
    Assert.AreEqual(result, sut);  //have we got the same data back
}
```

with the class

```
public class MyClass()
{
    public int MyInt{get;set;}
    public bool MyBool{get;set;}
    public Byte MyByte{get;set;}

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        //todo - needs to check all properties
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
}
```

and an Extension Methods

```
public static T Populate<T>(this T obj)
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties()
    {
        Type pt = prop.GetType();
        if (pt.IsPrimitiveType)
        {
            prop.SetMethod.Invoke(obj, pt.CreateValue());
        }
    }
}
public static object[] CreateValue<T>(this T type)
{
    return new [] {TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFromString(GetRandomString())};
}
public static object[] CreateValue2<T>(this T type)
{
    return new [] {Activator.CreateInstance(type)};
}
```

The CreateValue method does not work as the strings created are not numeric, or true/false, and the CreateValue2 just gives the default value which will always be the same.

So my question is how can I write a general method that will produce a random value of the required primitive type without an if/else chain (or switch) for the dozen or so primitive types?

I am not looking to extend this beyond primitive types yet (should be fairly straightforward to do so via recursion once primitives are solved)

Comment: Aside from dirty and unsafe hacks, I think you're stuck with a switch (or if/else). Is that really such a problem, though? You have to tailor the values to make *sense* in a given data type anyway. `DateTime`, `int`, `char` and `string` each have very different appropriate values.

Comment: In the end I went for a switch, it only resulted in 28 lines of code and 4 distinct cases (numeric, boolean, string and bytes).  I produced 4 helper methods to support this providing the actual data.  Saying that I did miss DateTime from the @Luaan list, but then that is a struct so handled elsewhere in my code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at [AutoPoco](http://autopoco.codeplex.com). It already has some factory methods that let you populate your objects with random data and it is also possible to add your own sources for creation of this elements.